# Failure to use bibliography in other tex file

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, xr

I have two .tex files: reftest.tex which contains the main details: reference, figure, equation; and cross_ref.tex. In cross_ref.tex, I want to cross-reference citation of refernece in the reftest.tex file. However, it was fail to cite. Could you help me to fix it? This is my code

In reftest.tex:

```
 \documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens}

\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is caption}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1} 
  y=x
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

%% Text of bibliographic item
\bibitem{S_Goossens}SMichel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

In cross_ref.tex

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{reftest}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens} in the reftest file

Figure \ref{fig:1} is figure in the reftest file

The  Eq. \eqref{eq:1} is a equation 

\end{document}
```

My output cannot show the citation number in cross_ref.tex file

[image]

Comment: xr only handles `\ref` and `\pageref` it does not touch `\cite` I suppose it could do, although no one has asked for that  in all these years:-)

Comment: You could use an external .bib file including in both documents separately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes. I just give a example in citation. I will change it name. Thank Jens Polz. Could you show an example code for this? I am not use .bib before.

Comment: @JensPolz: I think bib file is not good solution in my case. Because I already write full detail by using \bibitem. I tried to use  xcite, but it did not work

Comment: oh xcite is what you want here by the look at it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I used xcite but it still not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `xcite` it seems to be working. Note `xr-hyper` instead of `xr and the package loading order.

### `reftest.tex`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens}

\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1} 
  y=x
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

%% Text of bibliographic item
\bibitem{S_Goossens} Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

### `crossref.tex`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcite}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\externaldocument{reftest}
\externalcitedocument{reftest}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens} in the reftest file

Figure \ref{fig:1} is figure in the reftest file

The  Eq. \eqref{eq:1} is a equation 

\end{document}
```

### Output of `crossref.tex`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a solution.

If you use an external bibliographic file (literatur.bib):

```
    @BOOK{S_Goossens,
  title = {Some title},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1993},
  author = {Goossens, S. Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  address = {Reading, Massachusetts},
  owner = {polz},
  timestamp = {2016.03.24}
}
```

You just need to change your reftest.tex to use the external bibliography instead of using the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens}

\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1} 
  y=x
\end{equation}

\bibliography{literatur}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

If you now include the `\usepackage{bibentry}` command in the preamble of your cross_rex.tex and include the literatur.bib via `\nobibliography{literatur}{}`, which prevents printing the biblography, then it works the way you want.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{reftest}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
This is ref \cite{S_Goossens} in the reftest file

Figure \ref{fig:1} is figure in the reftest file

The  Eq. \eqref{eq:1} is a equation 

\nobibliography{literatur}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, My  bibliography is filled all reference by using \bibitem. It takes long time to convert it to bib style. I am looking for other solution

Comment: There are scripts available to convert the \bibitem entries to Bibtex, e.g. [here](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/tex2bib.html)